# The colors in ggplot do not correspond to the colors in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a histogram from the World Happiness Report and reorder the values. However, I´d like the colors from the plot to match the colors from the legend.

```
ggplot(Top102018, aes(x= reorder(Country, -Life.Ladder), y=Life.Ladder))+
geom_col(aes(fill=Country)) + 
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Country", 
                    labels = c("Finland", "Denmark", "Switzerland","Netherlands","Norway","Austria", "Sweden","New Zealand", "Luxembourg","United Kingdom"))  + 
theme_light()
```

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Colors don't match the legend because of the line : `scale_fill_discrete()`.
If you want the same order, use `reorder()` in the `fill` parameters too, not only in the `x =`

```
data.frame(
    Country     = c("Finland", "Denmark", "Switzerland"),
    Life.Ladder = c(10, 20, 15) 
) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Country, -Life.Ladder), y = Life.Ladder)) + geom_col(aes(fill = reorder(Country, -Life.Ladder))) +
    labs(fill = 'Country')  + 
    theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I included that because otherwise my countries are ordered alphabetically and not by size.

Comment: countries are ordered by size in the plot because of the function `reorder()`, but you're right, they are ordered alphabetically in the legend. Do you necessary need same order ?

Comment: if you want the same order, use `reorder()` in the `geom_col(fill = )` too. I edited the answer.